# Java process that invoke pkzip taking long time to zip

Tags: java, zip

I **must** use pkzip in my java program to zip (since standard java zip routine does not work on mainframe), I think it zip correctly, however it take a long time to finish. Here is mycode

```
 Runtime myruntime = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process newproc = myruntime.exec("c:\\app\\pkzipc.exe -add c:\\output\\test.zip c:\\doc\\foo.pdf c:\\doc\\bar.doc"");
```

`foo.pdf` and `bar.doc` are about 20MB each, if I execute this via commandline, then it take about a second to zip, but when I use the java, it take 30 min to 1 hours to finish the zipping. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are reading from the standard output and error streams of the child process. If pkzip generates output then it will be buffered by the operating system, and if the buffer fills up then you can expect the child process to block until the buffer is cleared.

The `Process` object has methods for obtaining the input, output and error streams. Create new threads that read from the output and error streams and either pipe them to `System.out` and `System.err`, or just discard the output if you don't care about it.

Comment: Thank you, do you think you can give me an sample code, Cameron? I really dont care about the output, I want to discard the output, please help.

Comment: I can't seem to find `pkzipc.exe` options. Isn't there an option to run with minimal output or no output at all?

Comment: @madth: will post my solution when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Java's `java.util.zip` API for manipulating .zip files, take a look at the [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/).

Comment: hi, I have to use pkzip for now. java.util.zip generate zip file that not readable on the mainframe.